# Programmatically embed ABPersonPicker (UIAddressBook) in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, abaddressbook

I would like to display a `UIAddressBook` inside my `UITabBarController` (which is also embedded in a `UINavigationController`) instead of displaying it modally every single time. In other words, I would like to access an address-book inside an already-existing tab bar controller and navigation controller. When I display it modally, the two disappear since it's an entirely new view. However, I could not find the documentation to embed it. Does anyone have any pointers?

Bonus: Is it possible to load a list of last names from a NSDictionary from an sqlite database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the control
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

The trick is to set the frame to `self.view.bounds`; that did it for me.